# English Redundancy

Tags: grammar

Is it okay to say, "monthly recurring", or can just "monthly" be used? Please sign up for a monthly recurring payment plan.

Comment: It depends. It is a little pleonastic (if something is monthly, the expectation is that it is recurring), but sometimes a little emphasis doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be pretty unusual to say *monthly recurring* particularly in your context. A *monthly payment plan* strongly implies that it is recurring. In my view, adding *recurring* to the phrase is redundant and would sound wordy to the listener without adding any value.